# getting runtime error in a C program

Tags: c, pointers, stack

Touching C after a long time. I am getting a run time error in the following code. The IDE[C-Free] which I am using is not showing the exact error but it shows *'StackMin.exe' has stopped working.*

Here, I am using two structures, `struct stack` is for stack and `struct AdvanedStack` is for storing two stacks. In the end I want to print the capacity of both the stacks which are in the `AdvancedStack`

Code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack {
    int capacity;
    int top;
    int *array;
  };

struct AdvancedStack{

    struct stack* elementStack;
    struct stack* minStack; 

};


struct stack* createStack()
{
    struct stack* myStack= (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    myStack->capacity=5;
    myStack->top=-1;
    myStack->array= malloc(myStack->capacity * sizeof(int));

    return myStack;

}

struct AdvancedStack* createAdvancedStack()
{
  struct AdvancedStack *myStack = (struct AdvancedStack*)malloc(sizeof(struct AdvancedStack));
    myStack->elementStack=createStack();
    myStack->minStack=createStack();
}

int main()
{
    struct AdvancedStack* advStack = createAdvancedStack();

   printf("%d",advStack->elementStack->capacity);
    printf("%d",advStack->minStack->capacity);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return `myStack` from the `createAdvancedStack()` function.

```
struct AdvancedStack* createAdvancedStack()
{
    struct AdvancedStack *myStack = malloc(sizeof(struct AdvancedStack)); //Don't cast the result of malloc

    myStack->elementStack=createStack();
    myStack->minStack=createStack();

    return myStack; //You forgot this
}
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to know why you should not cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Adding the `return` statement worked. Thanks for that. But is there any specific reason why to avoid casting the result of `malloc` here. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Also, main should return a value or call exit().

Comment: Read the link,  there are several reasons.

Comment: @VikasMangal , Read the link in my answer to know the answer.